# Last letter of text in div not redrawn in Safari when the div is repositioned in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I have a div:

```
<div id="loginHeaderText" >
     Service Cloud
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#loginHeaderText{
    display:inline; 
    position:relative; 
    bottom:40px;
    font-size: xx-large;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

when I refresh I see "Service Cloud" flash in the wrong spot, and then it's re-positioned according to it's css. However, the d in "Service Cloud" remains.

Here's what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAKLX.png

If I resize the window, the d disappears.

Any ideas? I guess a work around is to maybe to force a redraw on the page (like resizing the window)

Comment: I'm not sure we have quite enough information (HTML specifically) to help much.  Are you able to recreate the issue in a jsfiddle?

Comment: I haven't been able to recreate the problem in a isolated environment. Working on it though.

Comment: You say "when the div is repositioned". So does the position actually change while the div is on the screen already?